# How to hide Router navbar from privacy policy component

Tags: reactjs

Once the app launches privacy policy component will arrive. in this component, want to hide the routers navbar using React.

```
<li> 
<NavLink to="/profile" ><i className="fas fa-epi-profile"></i></NavLink> 
</li> 
<li> 
<NavLink to="/Home"><i className="fas fa-epi-good_picker"></i></NavLink> 
</li> 
<li> 
<NavLink to="/TaskListTabs"><i className="fas fa-epi-task"></i></NavLink> </li> 
<li> 
<NavLink to="/Notification"><i className="fas fa-epi-notification"></i></NavLink> 
</li>
```

( this is `App.js` file)

```
class App extends Component { render() { return ( <RoutersNav /> ); } }
```

but in privacy, component am using the navigation to another component which is code

```
<NavLink to="/login" className="float-right">
<input type="submit" className="btn" onClick={this.routeChange} name="accept" value="Accept" />
</NavLink>
```

once click on button giving error as `"Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>`

Comment: this is the code am using ( this is App.js file)
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RoutersNav />
    );
  }
}

In RouterNav component i have added navigation code.

Comment: cant see the code

Comment: this is the code am using ( this is App.js file)
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RoutersNav />
    );
  }
}

In RouterNav component i have added navigation code.

Answer (score 0):

In the navigationOptions of HomeScreen

```
static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', header: { visible:false } };
```

If you want to hide the header as the default behavior, you could instead pass navigationOptions to the navigator

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({ 
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen }, 
    LoginView: { screen: LoginView }, },
    navigationOptions:{ header:{ visible:false }});
```

Basic and simple way to hide a navbar

Answer (score 0):

you can try conditional rendering,
try to wrap your code inside `<BrowserRouter>`

```
class App extends Component { 

this.state={header:{ visible:false }};

render() { 

    return ( 
    if(this.state.header.visible) ?
    <RoutersNav />
    <ToastBody className="provacy-policy-content"> 
    <h4>Sample text</h4> Privacy Content 
    <input type="submit" className="btn float-left" name="accept" value="Accept" /> );
 :

    <ToastBody className="provacy-policy-content"> 
    <h4>Sample text</h4> Privacy Content 
    <input type="submit" className="btn float-left" name="accept" value="Accept" /> );

); } }
```

a good idea is ,

```
<BrowserRouter>
<NavLink to="/">/home</NavLink>
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: When am using this, Routers are hiding along with other component data also not displaying, return( <div className="privacy-policy-content">  Privacy Content         <input type="submit" className="btn float-left" name="accept" value="Accept" />
</div>  );
this is the privacy component short code, inside this component i have to hide roters.
am developing the mobile appl with react and displaying routers bar in footer.

Comment: no no, Toast code am using to display policy. that is in policy component.

Comment: above code is working, but in privacy, component am using the navigation to another component which is code " <NavLink  to="/login" className="float-right"><input type="submit" className="btn" onClick={this.routeChange} name="accept" value="Accept" /></NavLink>", once click on button givin error as "Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>"